# Wrong answer in basic goodness-of-fit test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, python, goodness-of-fit

I am following my lecture notes on this test:

[image]
[image]

However, when I calculate the expression $2\log \Lambda$ (Python script attached below), I get $21.8$ instead of $44.9$, which is quite far off. The given $\tilde{p}_i$ are the given probabilities under $H_0$, and $\hat{p}_i$ are the observed probabilities. Then, we should have
$$2\log\Lambda = 2\sum_i n_i\log\left(\frac{n_i}{n\tilde{p}_i}\right)=2\sum_i n_i\log\left(\frac{\hat{p}_i}{\tilde{p}_i}\right),$$
which is exactly what I thought I was calculating below. Any hints as to what is going on?

```
import scipy.stats as s
import numpy as np

observed_births = np.array([470, 515, 470, 457, 473, 381, 466, 457, 437, 396, 384, 394])
month_days = np.array([31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31])

observed_probabilities = observed_births / sum(observed_births)
null_hyp_probabilities = np.array([8.8, 8.5, 7.9, 8.3, 8.3, 7.6, 8.6, 8.3, 8.6, 8.5, 8.5, 8.3]) / 100
null_hyp_births = sum(observed_births) * null_hyp_probabilities

final_sum = 2 * sum(observed_births * np.log(observed_probabilities / null_hyp_probabilities))
print(final_sum)

pvalue = 1 - s.chi2.cdf(final_sum, df=11)
print(pvalue)
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Cross Validated. Since you marked your question as self-study, I won't spoon-feed you the full answer, but try to point you in the right direction.

Look at the numbers you're entering for your null hypothesis probabilities. Do they look like probabilities to you? Look at where you got them from. What exactly does the table say those numbers represent?

Comment: I have divided these by 100 so as to make them sum to 1, if that's what you're thinking about? (Although I now see that one has to scroll to the right in the code sample to see this.)

Comment: Ah, my bad. Sorry I didn't catch the 100 and thought there was an easy solution. In that case I can't see any problem with your math and my guess is it's an error in the lecture notes (perhaps they changed the data w.r.t. an earlier version and forgot to update the log-likelihood ratio and p-value as well). I also can only find an answer of 21.83, which has the much more moderate p-value of 0.0257.

Comment: Thank you. I also thought the p-value looked suspiciously small...